# Как сделать систему координат?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Помогите мне сделать систему координат x,y
Примерно такую:   [image]
только вот в центре у меня будет div (например mover) который можно будет перетаскивать по этой системе, вот пример
[image]
а когда центр div'a mover в правом верхнем углу то его координаты должны быть 0,5;0.5 например
черный квадрат это граница перетаскивания красного div'a
[image]
а если красный div mover будет слева в верхнем углу то координаты соответственно будут -0,5;0.5 например
[image]
Как перемещать div я понял с помощью draggable, а вот как сделать такую систему координат не пойму!
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: а что насчет canvas ? на нем можно нарисовать и систему и квадрат и двигать его можно (ну с доп либой одной например fabric, но все таки). Или принципиально с дивом надо ?

Comment: @alexoander ну div я потом могу растягивать с помощью resizable, в самом диве будет картинка, в идеале когда я тяну див то чтобы координаты не менялись, граница в виде черного квадрата тоже будет картинка

Comment: @alexoander в идеале видимость самой системы координат должна быть hidden, но должна работать

Comment: @ ну на самом деле сделать это достаточно просто . Я бы взял div родителя как координатную сетку и position relative , а див внутри - как position: absolute. Перемещение по координатам будет идти от 0:0 поэтому в js к координатам надо добавить например х-1 и у-1, чтобы "сместить" центр координат. Ну а движение - это draggable и ресайз - resizable. Картинка на фон - background. Выход за переделы - обработать и запретить (выставлять обратно 0:0). Если будет время - напишу код (хотя тут есть ребята,кто пошустрей меня его сделает).

Comment: @alexoander но почему то никто больше не пишет мне! По идее как я вижу нужно будет рисовать 3 квадрата, один это полотно для самих координат, второй это граница-картинка(черный квадрат) а третий это красный квадрат. Правильно я думаю?

Answer (score 1):

Я написал такую нехилую плоскость координат:

```js
var one = 25; // Указывает, сколько пикселей считать за единицу
var coordPos = function(val_0) {
  var plane = {x: $('.coordinate-plane').offset().left, y: $('.coordinate-plane').offset().top},
      ox = $('.coordinate-plane .coordinate-plane__y').offset().left,
      oy = $('.coordinate-plane .coordinate-plane__x').offset().top;
  var coord;
  if(typeof(val_0) == 'string'){
    coord = {
      top: (($(val_0).offset().top - plane.y) - (oy - plane.y)) / one * -1,
      left: (($(val_0).offset().left - plane.x) - (ox - plane.x)) / one,
      right: (($(val_0).offset().left + $(val_0).outerWidth() - plane.x) - (ox - plane.x)) / one,
      bottom: (($(val_0).offset().top + $(val_0).outerHeight() - plane.y) - (oy - plane.y)) / one * -1
    }
  }else if(typeof(val_0) == 'object'){
    coord = {left: (val_0.x * one) + ox - plane.x, top: (val_0.y * one * -1) + oy - plane.y}
  };
  return coord;
};

$(function() {
  // Узнаём координаты элемента
  console.log({x: coordPos('#elem__0').top, y: coordPos('#elem__0').left}); // верхний-левый угол
  console.log({x: coordPos('#elem__0').top, y: coordPos('#elem__0').right}); // верхний-правый угол
  console.log({x: coordPos('#elem__0').bottom, y: coordPos('#elem__0').left}); // нижний-левый угол
  console.log({x: coordPos('#elem__0').bottom, y: coordPos('#elem__0').right}); // нижний-правый угол
  
  // Узнаём положение по координатам
  console.log({left: coordPos({x: 1, y: 1}).left, top: coordPos({x: 1, y: 1}).top});
  
  // Устанавливаем элементу координаты
  var left = coordPos({x: 2, y: 2}).left;
  var top = coordPos({x: 2, y: 2}).top - $('#elem__0').outerHeight(); // Минусовать нужно потом, что оно всегда ищету нижнюю границу, по этому нужно отнимать высоту блока, что бы получить положение верхнего края
  $('#elem__0').css({top: top, left: left});
});
```

```css
.coordinate-plane {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 435px;
}
.coordinate-plane__x {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.coordinate-plane__y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="coordinate-plane">
  <div class="coordinate-plane__x"></div>
  <div class="coordinate-plane__y"></div>
  <div class="coordinate-plane__plane">
    <div id="elem__0" style="width: 21px; height: 21px;position: absolute; border: 2px solid green; top: 166.5px; left: 324px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Перемещение я думаю можно сделать так (код ниже - перемещении по вертикали - по аналогии (свойство TOP)). При движении рассчитывать координаты дива от границ окна и сравнивать с нарисованной координатной сеткой ...

```js
let div = document.body.querySelector('div');

let flag = false;

function move() {
  if(flag) {
    this.style.left = event.pageX - 20 + 'px';    
  } 
}

div.addEventListener('mousemove', move);

div.onmousedown = function(e) { 
  flag = true;
}

div.onmouseup = function(e) {
  flag = false;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```